# Messages sent in Skype don't get received

Tags: c#, winforms, skype, skype4com

I'm trying to send multiple messages in Skype. They start sending, but don't finish; they just keep on loading. I'm using a timer with the interval of 5 seconds. How do I fix this?

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _skype.SendMessage(onlineUsers[i], form3.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Looks kinda spammy. What are you making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a C# programmer, I program in python but the solution is still pretty simple. First of all it is because that Skype api has been dropped and no longer is supported by skype. There is a workaround however, you can send messages like this:

```
skype.Client.OpenMessageDialog(username, message_to_send)
skype.Client.Focus()
```

Then you'll need to send an "ENTER" keystroke.

If this doesn't work get an older skype version